# Deleting the nth node in a linked list, can't delete first node?

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, nodes

Below is a function that is designed to delete the nth node in a linked list. For example if I called `deleteN(head, 2)` it would delete the 2nd node in the list.

```
node *deleteN(node *head, int n)
{

    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;


    if (n == 1)
    {
        node *temp = head;
        //printf("the element is %d\n", temp->data);
        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return head;
    }

    head->next = deleteN(head->next, n-1);

    return head;

}
```

It works fine unless you call e.g. `deleteN(head, 1)`, which is supposed to delete the first node in the list, but when I call another function to print the list, it prints random addresses instead.

Examples of what is happening in a list of **4 nodes** that contain the integer values **23**, **24**, **25**, and **26** in order (what is called in main then output):

**Test case 1 (PASS):**

`deleteN(head, 2);`

`printList(head);`

**Output:**

23

25

26

**Test case 2 (PASS):**

`deleteN(head, 3);`

`printList(head);`

**Output:**

23

24

26

**Test case 3 (PASS):**

`deleteN(head, 4);`

`printList(head);`

**Output:**

23

24

25

**Test case 4 (FAIL):**

`deleteN(head, 1);`

`printList(head);`

**Output:**

34223223

34234242

34342343

34343434

34234434

(more garbage numbers then segfault)

My question is how can I modify my code so that it can delete the first node as well?

Comment: `head = deleteN(head, 1);`

Comment: ^This is also correct, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a value from deleteN but you don't use it. You need to update `head` with

```
head = deleteN(head, n);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from your question, but I suspect that you are not updating head, when calling deleteN().

This should work:

```
head=deleteN(head,1);
printList(head);
```

I think this is what you are doing:

```
deleteN(head,1);
printList(head);
```

Comment: Your hunch was right, I should have paid more attention to main rather than assuming the problem was in the deleteN function!

Comment: @KarimElsheikh I'm glad AMADANON was able to help.  If you agree that their answer is correct, please accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Riley the OP already accepted my answer, perhaps because I posted it a little earlier so the OP saw it first.

Comment: We were typing at the same time, Jim submitted first. That's the way it goes, I'll get reputation on the next one.